# How to distinguish between two encrypted / secured PDF files

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have two secured pdf files. One has a password and the other one is secured but without password. I am using PDF Box.
How can I identify which file has password and which one is secured but without password?

Answer (score 1):

PDF's have two type of encryption -

- **Owner password** - Password set by PDF owner / creator to restrict its usage (*e.g. edit, print, copy etc*)
- **User password** - Password set to open / view the PDF

PDF can have only owner password or both; but not only user password. In either case the PDF is termed to be encrypted and there is no direct API to distinguish between two kind of encryption.

In case of `PDFBox` you can use below code snippet to determine if it is encrypted or not; and distinguish whether it has only owner password or both.

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("path/to/pdf"));
boolean hasOwnerPwd = false;
boolean hasUserPwd = false;
if(pdfDoc.isEncrypted()){
    hasOwnerPwd = true;
    try{
        StandardDecryptionMaterial sdm = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(null);
        pdfDoc.openProtection(sdm);
        hasUserPwd = true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

See `PDFBox` API docs [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.9/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#isEncrypted()) and [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.9/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/encryption/StandardDecryptionMaterial.html#StandardDecryptionMaterial(java.lang.String)).

**EDIT** Thanks to Tilman to point out latest code and alternate way to determine / distinguish between two encryption. Updated the code snippet and post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce.I have already used Itext LIB.for pdf password checking,Its work on windows server only when i deployed on Linux server i got following exception.Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z* - **A** This is a completely different issue; thus, it should have been addressed in a separate question. **B** That issue has been subject to many stackoverflow questions and answers before. As a hint: You have multiple BouncyCastle versions on your classpath getting in each other's way.

Comment: @Bond: One can of course find out whether it has an empty user password: call openProtection() with an empty password. Btw your code is outdated, correct code is PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(...)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks for pointing out the latest code and alternate way. It helped get past the hangover on earlier PDFbox version I used long back :) Have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: gr8! glad it helped you. Do accept the answer for benefit of future readers.

Comment: Also good to know, and it was part of the question: to find out whether whatever password you used is the user or the owner password, check the permissions. if doc.getCurrentAccessPermission().isOwnerPermission() == true, then you used the owner password.