# pdfbox "isEncrypted" API is not giving desired results

Tags: java, pdfbox

Here is my code to know if the PDF that I am reading is password protected or not:

```
public static boolean isPasswordProtected(File document)
{
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        PDDocument originalPdfDoc = PDDocument.load(document);
        ret = originalPdfDoc.isEncrypted();     
        originalPdfDoc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    return ret;
}
```

But for certain PDFs though they are not password protected, it's still returning true. Is this the right way to know if the pdf is password protected or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you need to know. Some PDF files are encrypted with the empty user password, this is done if these have restricted permissions. If you want to accept these, you should try to unlock them with openProtection():

```
doc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));
```

and only if that fails (with a CryptographyException), return true.

(This answer is for 1.8.* only)

See also here:
[How to distinguish between two encrypted / secured PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019976/how-to-distinguish-between-two-encrypted-secured-pdf-files)